# How can I make a selected grid evenly spaced?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Imagine I have a quad mesh composed of several grids:

[image: A triangle mesh made up from three grids]

Now that I changed the outline of one grid,

[image: The above mentioned mesh with edited outline looking messed up]

I would like to make its inner vertices evenly spaced, as if I deleted those and executed Grid Fill on the outline:

[image: Fixed mesh]

The reason I'm avoiding Grid Fill is it's bad at detecting corners, which is especially painful on higher resolution meshes:

[image: Messed-up mesh generated by Grid Fill with auto-detected parameters]

I'm aware of LoopTools' Gstretch function, but it's also impractical on high resolution meshes.

Is there a quicker method of doing this?

Comment: I think you should give a try to Proportional Editing, you can select from multiple falloffs. "O" for shortcut.

Comment: @Tsybe Aside from being inaccurate, as of now it's still impossible to prevent other parts of the mesh being influenced by Proportional Editing while making them still visible without a plugin hosted on Gumroad... But thanks anyway, I wouldn't have known such plugin exists if you didn't mention that.

Comment: Try selecting all the faces you want to "smooth" (you may have to omit the outer "rim" depending on whether or not you want to preserve it's shape), and then pick _Vertex > Smooth Vertices_ from the menu at the top of the viewport. You can adjust the number of "smoothing steps" from the operator panel that appears in the bottom left.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you! Although not what I originally asked for, that's a surprisingly better approach for my current use case (modeling flat cloth pieces for sewing simulation).